# Unable to play incoming call audio HTML

Tags: javascript, html, web-deployment, html5-audio, pusher

I'm sending a call from one user to another by using pusher notifications. But when I open up a modal for ACCEPT CALL or REJECT CALL in second user's screen I'm getting the following error while playing audio of call notification because the second user has not yet interacted with screen:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.
```

Anyone knows how can I fix this notification audio issue?

Comment: You can't play it automatically, the user has to interact with the document first. There is no way around that.

Comment: @cloned do you have any idea then how Facebook is doing this?

Comment: How Facebook is doing what?

Comment: never used fb messenger, but you are sure they are not using the messenger app? But sorry, can't really help you here.

Comment: Ohh! I just found that even Facebook is unable to play audio if 2nd person refreshes his page.